# how to exit shell script when python code returns sys.exit(1)

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

function createContent() {
python - <<END
import sys
if(true):
  print('true')
else:
  sys.exit(1)  
END
}

if [ "${CREATE_REQUEST}" != "" ]; then
  createContent
fi

#next operations
```

This is a shell script. There is python method defined in there called `createContent` . That method is called when `CREATE_REQUEST` Env variable is set. The problem is that when `createContent` runs `sys.exit(1)` the python function breaks but the shell script does not exit there. All other remaining code in the shell script continues to execute. Why is that happening and how to ensure that if python exits with `sys.exit(1)` the calling code either handles it or the shell just returns the control with correct exit code.

Comment: Note: `createContent` is not a Python method. It's a shell function.

Comment: You need `set -e`, not `set -x`.  Then the shell script will stop after python says `sys.exit(1)`

Comment: `createContent || exit 1`

Comment: unrelated, but your python code isn't syntatically valid

Comment: If we fix the python by saying `if(True):` (or better, `if True:`), then the `sys.exit` isn't called. Perhaps make this a working example that always does `sys.exit` and does an echo at the end of the bash script so we can see the difference in the output text.

Comment: You can exit a bash script with the "exit" command so another way to work arround this would be to add this command after calling the sys.exit(1) in python or even instead of it

Comment: @YourHelper I believe this python code is just an example, not the real application. Presumably in the real code the python script can be successful and they don't wait to exit the shell script.

Comment: that python code is just a sample. actual code is correct syntax wise and does sys.exit in error conditions.

Comment: @jez what is the difference between `set -e` and `set -x`

Comment: @colossal They're two different shell options, independent of each other.  `set -e` means "exit as soon as there's a problem" (i.e. a non-zero return code from a pipeline). It can be countermanded with `set +e`.   `set -x` means "echo what you're doing as you do it" and can be countermanded with `set +x`.  For the complete set of bash shell options:   https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: Thank you all. One follow up question. Seems like there is a difference between python's `sys.exit(1)` and shell's `exit 1`. The K8 pod where this script runs in one the pods, shows `Error` state when `sys.exit(1)` is called as compare to `Completed` when shell's `exit 1` is called. Not sure if both are doing something different.

Answer (score 1):

By default, shell scripts do not exit if a command returns non zero (fails). You can set this behaviour with `set -e`.

If you don't want `set -e` for the whole script, you can add it to the function only:

```
createContent () {
python - <<"END" || exit 1
# python code
"END"
}
```

You could also exit only for a specific error code:

```
python - <<"END"; (($?==1)) && exit 1
```

You should double quote `END`, to ensure the script text is passed verbatim (without quotes the text is subject to shell expansion).

If you don't want it built in to the function by default, you can add the same logic when calling the function:

```
createContent || exit 1
```

Comment: This works good but one thing I am noticing is that python's `sys.exit(1)` seems to be different than shell's `exit 1`. The k8 pod shows its status as `Error` where this script runs in a container where as in cases where shell returns `exit 1` for some other use case shows `Completed`. Is `sys.exit(1)` different from `exit 1` ?

Comment: @colossal: Both forms end the current process (closing open file handles and other cleanup tasks first) and return status code 1 to the calling process. If you see a different behaviour, ask a new question about this, and don't forget how you call the respective process from the container.

Comment: @colossal They are essentially equivalent commands yes. The different behaviour might be something to do with the Python script being a child of the shell script. I recommend asking a new question, tagged kubernetes.